# How do the non-base cases work in recursion?

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion

I would like to understand recursion fully. I understand the part where it has to meet the base case (n=0) before returning 1, that part I understand completely. When it meets the base case condition, it returns to the instance that called it which is n=1, that I also understand.

How does it now increment and goes back to n=2, how does the mechanism behind it work to make it go back up to n=5? I guess I am missing something here.

```
<?php

function factorial( $n ) {

  // Base case
  if ( $n == 0 ) {
    echo "Base case: $n = 0. Returning 1...<br>";
    return 1;
  }

  // Recursion
  echo "$n = $n: Computing $n * factorial( " . ($n-1) . " )...<br>";
  $result =  $n * factorial( $n-1 );
  echo "Result of $n * factorial( " . ($n-1) . " ) = $result. Returning $result...<br>";
  return $result;
}

echo "The factorial of 5 is: " . factorial( 5 );


?>
```

This is supposed to be the output

```
5 = 5: Computing 5 * factorial( 4 )...
4 = 4: Computing 4 * factorial( 3 )...
3 = 3: Computing 3 * factorial( 2 )...
2 = 2: Computing 2 * factorial( 1 )...
1 = 1: Computing 1 * factorial( 0 )...
Base case: 0 = 0. Returning 1...
Result of 1 * factorial( 0 ) = 1. Returning 1...
Result of 2 * factorial( 1 ) = 2. Returning 2...
Result of 3 * factorial( 2 ) = 6. Returning 6...
Result of 4 * factorial( 3 ) = 24. Returning 24...
Result of 5 * factorial( 4 ) = 120. Returning 120...
The factorial of 5 is: 120
```

Comment: When the function `return`, the result is sent back to the calling function. and the calling function continue executing, until it `return` a value to the previous calling function and so on

Comment: @Cid understand that part, but when reading the code, I see how it returns it to the last instance which was n =1, but I don't understand how it now returns it to n=2, or is it something I just have to memorize ????

Comment: Picture a Russian Matryoshka doll (Babushka) - this is sort of what happens; the function calls itself (`$n * factorial( $n-1 );`) as many times as needed to run through the $n calls to itself.

Comment: it returns 2 because of `2 * 1`. The 1 coming from the `n = 1` return value

Comment: If you search in your browser for "introduction to recursion", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

All the data related to your function or method when it is called is stored on a stack. So let us say you make a call to your function `factorial(5)` for value 5. Now when you call your function with parameter 5. It is put onto the stack and the program tries to calculate its value, now while calculating it value your program finds out that its value depends on `factorial(5-1)` that is `5*factorial(4)` so overall computation of calculating `factorial(5)` is stopped it remains in stack and your program will calculate value of `factorial(4)` by putting it in stack. In order to determine `factorial(4)` , your program will need value of `factorial(3)` and therefore i.e will put onto the stack , So the current stack will look somewhat like `[[factorial(5) with all its data] , [factorial(4) with all its data] , [factorial(3) with all its data]]` Overall state of the whole function is maintained similarly your program will further put `factorial(2)` and `factorial(1)` onto the stack. Now if there will be no base condition then your program will crash due to `stackoverflow` as your program will keep on filling the stack with other function calls like `factorial(0)` , `factorial(-1)` and so on. So we need a base case. So when your program finds the condition where `n==0` it gets it value directly as and it stops further pushing other function calls to stack and then it starts processing the current stack so once it gets value of `factorial(0)` it uses it to calculate value of `factorial(1)` and pops `factorial(1)` and all its data from the stack after returning the value of `facotrial(1)` to `factorial(2)` (as factorial(1) was called from `factorial(2) )` now `factorial(2)` does the same thing. So finally the stack will pop the elements from it as they were pushed and the final value of your function which you called initially will be calculated i.e. `factorial(5)` .